# Swift 4 decoding doubles from JSON

Tags: json, swift

I though I had this concept nailed!

I am sending a JSON which contains a double.

```
{"elementName":"Security:Driver","element_Cost":"650"}
```

I've created CodingKeys and a decoder extension but I still get a Type Mismatch error when I send the data.

```
struct ElementCosts: Content {
    let elementName: String
    let elementCost: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case elementCost = "element_Cost"
        case elementName
    }
}

extension ElementCosts: Decodable {

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        elementCost = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .elementCost)
        elementName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .elementName)
    }
}
```

Looking at some of the other posts here I cannot see what I've done wrong.

I've tried to change the Data type to Int but still has the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read the error message. `Codable` error messages are very descriptive. It even tells you the actual type (`xyz found instead`). And you don't need the extension, you get the initializer for free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"650"` is a string, not a number.

You can parse it like this

```
let elementCostString = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .elementCost)
elementConst = Double(elementCostString) ?? 0
```

Or change it to be a String on your model, whichever works better for you.

Comment: Only thing I'd change here is throwing an error if it can't be converted to a double, rather than coalescing to 0.  Seems like that'd be more likely to be the behavior you want if the data is bad.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I totally agree, however I think that SO answer code should be concise and focus on the problem, in this case parsing that JSON data. Error handling and other things are better left to the reader.

Comment: The issue is that JSON has to be stringified to be sent, converting numbers into strings. Therefore I need to convert it back. I thought that decoding it using a Double.self would tell the decoder that it should try and decode the String as a Double.

Comment: @salongley while JSON is basically a string representation, there's a difference between `"650"` and `650`, notice the quotes in the first one. The first one will be interpreted as a String, the second one will be interpreted as a number. If you have control over creating the JSON, you should look into generating it without the quotes, then you won't need to parse it as a String.