# How to coerce Swift's JSON Loader to parse decimal from a string

Tags: swift

I'm trying to intialize an array of `Item`s from a json file. To this end, I followed [Apple's tutorial with re: to doing it (The algorithm is in data.swift but I'll post an abridged version down as well)](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation) My issue is that the API I'm pulling data from serves up decimals in quotation marks leading me to get the error

> typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "average_cost", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

What Apple's json decoder expects:

```
[{
        "company": "Bioseed",
        "item_class": "Seeds",
        "name": "9909",
        "stock": 0,
        "average_cost": 0.00,  // Doubles without quotation marks
        "otc_price": 0.00,
        "dealer_price": 0.00,
        "ctc_price": 0.00
}]
```

Sample data from my API saved in `items.json`:

```
[{
        "company": "Bioseed",
        "item_class": "Seeds",
        "name": "9909",
        "stock": 0,
        "average_cost": "0.00",
        "otc_price": "0.00",
        "dealer_price": "0.00",
        "ctc_price": "0.00"
}]
```

I could probably rewrite my API to serve decimals and ints without quotation marks however it's already being used by other applications so I would rather not risk breaking something.

So is there a way to tell the decoded to ignore the quotation marks?

Item struct:

```
struct Item : Decodable {

    var company: String
    var item_class: String
    var name: String
    var stock: Int
    var average_cost: Decimal
    var otc_price: Decimal
    var dealer_price: Decimal
    var ctc_price: Decimal
```

Loading function:

```
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String, as type: T.Type = T.self) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

Calling it:

```
    let items: [Item] = load("items.json")
    print(items)
```

Comment: Anything that's enclosed in `"` is treated as a String by `Codable`. If you want to convert these values to Ints or Decimals, you'll have to write that conversion code yourself, by overriding the `init(from:)` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 4 decoding doubles from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119001/swift-4-decoding-doubles-from-json). Another question that might be of interest, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935705/using-codable-with-key-that-is-sometimes-an-int-and-other-times-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would implement this:

```swift
struct Item : Decodable {
    let company: String
    let itemClass: String
    let name: String
    let stock: Int
    let averageCost: Decimal
    let otcPrice: Decimal
    let dealerPrice: Decimal
    let ctcPrice: Decimal

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case company
        case itemClass = "item_class"
        case name
        case stock
        case averageCost = "average_cost"
        case otcPrice = "otc_price"
        case dealerPrice = "dealer_price"
        case ctcPrice = "ctc_price"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.company = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .company)
        self.itemClass = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .itemClass)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.stock = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .stock)

        guard
            let averageCost = Decimal(string: try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .averageCost))
        else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .averageCost, in: container, debugDescription: "not a Decimal.")
        }

        guard
            let otcPrice = Decimal(string: try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .otcPrice))
        else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .otcPrice, in: container, debugDescription: "not a Decimal.")
        }

        guard
            let dealerPrice = Decimal(string: try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .dealerPrice))
        else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .dealerPrice, in: container, debugDescription: "not a Decimal.")
        }

        guard
            let ctcPrice = Decimal(string: try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .ctcPrice))
        else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .ctcPrice, in: container, debugDescription: "not a Decimal.")
        }


        self.averageCost = averageCost
        self.otcPrice = otcPrice
        self.dealerPrice = dealerPrice
        self.ctcPrice = ctcPrice
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could keep the String properties in your model, and convert to decimals on access

```swift
struct Item : Decodable {
    let company: String
    let itemClass: String
    let name: String
    let stock: Int
    let _averageCost: String
    let _otcPrice: String
    let _dealerPrice: String
    let _ctcPrice: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case company
        case itemClass = "item_class"
        case name
        case stock
        case _averageCost = "average_cost"
        case _otcPrice = "otc_price"
        case _dealerPrice = "dealer_price"
        case _ctcPrice = "ctc_price"
    }

    var averageCost: Decimal {
        return Decimal(string: _averageCost) ?? .zero
    }

    // ... and so on for the other properties
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gereon! However I was looking for a more succinct way to do this as the app would include dozens of models just like this. So I'm guessing there's no work around?

Comment: Added a possible alternative to my answer

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain why?